# columns during table creation using ORMLite not aligned with Bean

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

I have created a bean with the following fields for android application

```
@DatabaseField(generatedId=true)
private int id;
@DatabaseField
private String name;
@DatabaseField(unique=true)
private String emailId;
@DatabaseField
private String mobile;
@DatabaseField(unique=true)
private String loginName;
@DatabaseField
private String loginPassword;
@DatabaseField
private String confirmPassword;
@DatabaseField
private String securityQuestion;
@DatabaseField
private String securityPassword;
@DatabaseField
private String transactionPassword;
@DatabaseField
private String uac;
```

But, When I view the DB Table using the Questoid SQLite Manager in my Eclipse IDE, I do not see columns created in the same order as declared in the bean, rather I see something like this as shown below:

```
CREATE TABLE user (confirmPassword VARCHAR, emailId VARCHAR, uac VARCHAR,
    loginPassword VARCHAR, mobile VARCHAR, name VARCHAR, securityPassword VARCHAR,
    transactionPassword VARCHAR id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT);
```

This order is very difficult from readability and debugging perspective. 
Are there any ways to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised that the order.  I believe it is how Android orders the fields inside of the classes.  [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) is just iterating through the fields in the class.  I don't have any solution to the order problem aside from trying to move the fields around in your object.  Definitely a HACK however.

If you look at how ORMLite configures classes in Sqlite through JDBC, you can see that it matches the order of the class directly:

```
public class AllTypes {
    @DatabaseField
    String stringField;
    @DatabaseField
    boolean booleanField;
    @DatabaseField
    Date dateField;
    @DatabaseField
    byte byteField;
    @DatabaseField
    short shortField;
    @DatabaseField
    int intField;
    @DatabaseField
    long longField;
    @DatabaseField
    float floatField;
    @DatabaseField
    double doubleField;
}
```

Here's the SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `alltypes` (`stringField` VARCHAR , `booleanField` BOOLEAN ,
    `dateField` TIMESTAMP , `byteField` TINYINT , `shortField` SMALLINT ,
    `intField` INTEGER , `longField` BIGINT , `floatField` FLOAT ,
    `doubleField` DOUBLE PRECISION )
```

So this is an Android only issue.

Comment: Currently I am seeing this issue on Android API level 10. But, When I used Android API level 15, I didn't find this issue.

Comment: In the Android Manifest.xml file, If I specify the MinSDK as 9 and MaxSDK as 15, can this problem be solved?
I just randomly thought about this idea, but need to check if that would work.

Comment: This is about which SDK version you are using, not configuration changes.  The newer SDK must handle the field order differently @user1564626.

Comment: I am using Android 2.3.3, But is it possible to import Android 4.0 SDK and get support for 2.3.3 ?

Comment: I'm not sure.  I don't think you can import a new SDK but still use the old one @user1564626.

Comment: No, I shall remove the older SDK. I shall have only 1 Android SDK 4.0.3 imported to my project. But, the Minimum SDK that my application support should start with API level 9 (2.3.3) till API level 15(4.0.3) configured in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: so I am encountering this issue sporadically, after I `dropTable` and recreate it in app, sometimes, how do I use `queryForId` from raw results, when I need to know the exact index of the id to use it? the catch being that the index of the id field will change

Comment: Please ask this on the mailing @CQM.